# Мониторинг появления новых страниц на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование

Какими способами можно отслеживать появление новых страниц на сайте? Например, на сайте example.com расположено множество страниц вида: example.com/123456, example.com/234567, example.com/345678, ... При этом на сайте отсутствуют внутренние ссылки на эти страницы, то есть с "главной" страницы невозможно перейти ни на одну из интересующих нас страниц, но при этом если ввести в адресную строку URL конкретной страницы, то она будет загружена. Можно ли как то мониторить появление новых страниц на таком сайте, если название новый страницы генерируется произвольно?

Comment: Если сайт не предоставляет информацию о появлении страниц, то нельзя, кроме как полным перебором возможных вариантов

Comment: Некоторые сайты генерируют sitemap.xml, может Вам повезло? (пример - https://www.sitemaps.org/sitemap.xml )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@andreymal прав, за некоторым исключением: воспользоваться поисковой машиной (sphinx для самостоятельной работы) либо подписаться на рассылку мыла в гугле на обновления.
Это не гарантирует моментальное уведомление о создании новой страницы, это гарантирует лишь то, что при обнаружении изменений роботом гугла ты будешь уведомлен об этом.

Comment: Можно поподробнее на счёт Sphinx и рассылки в Google на обновления?

Comment: sphinx это поисковая система с открытым исходным кодом (php, python), использование её увеличит объём данных на харде, полагаю потребуется не менее терабайта. О подписке в гугле: есть возможность подписаться на получение писем, при обнаружении роботом гугла некоторых слов (ссылку не проси не помню... а видел где-то в доках гугла)

Comment: Поисковая машина тоже должна откуда-то узнавать информацию о страницах. Если неоткуда - то результатов в поиске не будет

Comment: @andreymal поисковая машина, на то и поисковая машина, что проверяет каждую ссылку на наличие ссылок + на обновления обновляемых страниц, Так, что если кто-то где-то в публичном доступе даст новую ссылку на искомый сайт, то придёт уведомление

Comment: А если не даст, то не придёт